# Search and replace CDATA with regex

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to create a bash script that looks at some export files and does a search and replace on some CDATA values. I need to extract a value from the existing string, and replace it with a new string containing that value.

For example:

- Search for: `<![CDATA[{"original_image":"9","cropped_image":15}]]>`
- Replace with: `<![CDATA[9]]>`
- Where the replaced string contains JUST value from the
  "original_image":"9"

I'm decent with Regex and I can get the value I need with: `^[^\d]*(\d+)`

I'm just not sure how to do the rest, I assume I do this with `sed` or `awk`. Once again, thanks to anyone willing to help.

Comment: No standard UNIX tool will understand what `\d` means. If you want to match a digit then use `[0-9]`,

Comment: Good to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i 's/\(<!\[CDATA\[\)[^][]*"original_image":"\([0-9]*\)[^][]*\(]]>\)/\1\2\3/g' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/u02aAq):

```
s='<![CDATA[{"original_image":"9","cropped_image":15}]]>'
sed 's/\(<!\[CDATA\[\)[^][]*"original_image":"\([0-9]*\)[^][]*\(]]>\)/\1\2\3/g' <<< "$s"
# => <![CDATA[9]]>
```

**Details**

- `\(<!\[CDATA\[\)` - Group 1: `<![CDATA[` substring
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `"original_image":"` - a literal substring
- `\([0-9]*\)` - Group 2: zero or more digits
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\(]]>\)` - Group 3: `]]>` substring

The `\1\2\3` replacement pattern is a concatenation of the three group values.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!